# Is there an LDAP library that handles all of the RFC4511 logic?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

RFC4511 (section 4.5.3.1) shows that if a directory is split over several servers, then the client needs to wade through several redirections in order to get a definitive answer.  It seems silly that every client would need to do this.  Is there any (free) library that does all of this logic and just returns a GOOD/BAD/UNKNOWN result?

Comment: if you are talking about following referrals, Im pretty sure that OpenLDAP client library has an option to enable that behavior.

Comment: I didn't see that in the documentation.  Do you have a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_set_option

LDAP_OPT_REFERRAL_URLS
Sets/gets an array containing the referral URIs associated to the LDAP handle. outvalue must be a char ***, and the caller is responsible of freeing the returned string by calling ldap_memvfree(3), while invalue must be a NULL-terminated char *const *; the library duplicates the corresponding string. This option is OpenLDAP specific.
LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS
Determines whether the library should implicitly chase referrals or not. invalue must be const int *; its value should either be LDAP_OPT_OFF or LDAP_OPT_ON. outvalue must be int *.

Comment: I read this option as saying that it would gather the referral URIs and put them in a list.  I didn't read it as saying that they library would redirect its query without any client interaction.  Was I wrong?

Comment: I read it as the library will follow them for you.  And I've seen code which assumes that it's the case.  I didn't test that scenario though.